# ruby on rails select not defaulting to current value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, select

I'm currently using a select as follows (within a form):

```
<% form_for :search, :url => search_path, :html => {:method => :get} do |f| %>
        <%=  select('search', :type, options_for_select(['Artist', 'Track'])) %>
        <%= f.text_field :query %>
<% end %>
```

This works, but when I perform a search, it defaults back to artist even if the user selected Track before searching.  How can I correct this?

Automatically selecting the current value works for radio buttons:

```
<% form_for @search, :url => search_path, :html => {:method => :get} do |f| %>
  <p class="radio_button">
  <%= f.label :type_track, 'Search tracks' %>
  <%= f.radio_button :type, 'Track' %>
  </p>
  <p class="radio_button">
  <%= f.label :type_artist, 'Search artists' %>
  <%= f.radio_button :type, 'Artist' %>
  </p>
  <p class="text_field">
  <%= f.label :query, 'Search query' %>
  <%= f.text_field :query, :class => 'auto_focus' %>
  </p>
  <p class="submit">
  <%= submit_tag 'Go' %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Any help getting this to work will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must use the [select](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder/select) form builder:

```
<%= f.select(:type, [["text1", "value1"], ["text2", "value2"], ...]) %>
```

Comment: sorry - what should the array of pairs_name_id look like..?

Comment: [["text", value], ["text2", "value2"]]

Comment: you should accept tokland's answer, it's the least to do when you receive a correct answer

Comment: I was going to!  I had to wait long enough to mark it, though, and then had to leave my office.